# DolphinDB: Most efficient way to combine a STRING and a FLOAT vector as a row of table?

Tags: vector, dolphindb

I want to combine a STRING scalar and a FLOAT vector and convert to a row of table (which is of [STRING, FLOAT, ...,FLOAT] type).

Suppose the variables are defined as follows:

```
str="a"
v=[0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
```

I expect the output to be:

```
strCol  col0    col1    col2    col3
a       0.3     0.6     0.7     0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed script can be applied to vectors of any length:

```
str="a"
v=[0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
t = table(matrix(v).transpose())
update t set strCol = str
reorderColumns!(t,`strCol)
```

Check table t:

```
strCol  col0    col1    col2    col3
a       0.3     0.6     0.7     0.8
```